# Jquery, json doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display some data get with ajax.

I don't know why is stopping to work.

After `$.getJson ... console.log(json)` display the correct value but append on the container doesn't work.
The selector container is correct, I've already tested with foo value.
(i'm trying to append json on container but the final objectives is to fill table)
If someone had any idea? I didn't have any error on console just no display.

```
    console.log("vocabulaire module loaded");
var initData = function(){
    $("#Module").html("");
    $("#Module").append("<div id='gestion-box'></div>");
    $("#Module").append("<div id='container'></div>");
    $("#gestion-box").append("<div id='ajout'></div>");
    $("#gestion-box").append("<div id='search'></div>");
    $("#ajout").append("<h5>Ajout</h5>");
    $("#ajout").append("<input id='word' name='hiragana' placeholder='ひらがな' type='text' class='form-control'/>");
    $("#ajout").append("<input id='translation' name='traduction' placeholder='Traduction' type='text' class='form-control'/>");
    $("#ajout").append("<button id='button-ajout' class='btn'>OK</button>");
    $("#search").append("<h5>Search</h5>");
    $("#search").append("<input name='word-search' id='word-search' placeholder='Search' type='text' class='form-control'/>");
    $("#search").append("<button id='button-all' class='btn btn-info'>Tous</button>");
    $("#search").append("<button id='button-unknow' class='btn btn-success'>Non connu</button>");
    $("#search").append("<button id='button-know' class='btn btn-warning'>Connu</button>");
    $.getJSON( "./modules/vocabulaire/data.json", function( json ) {
        console.log(json);
        $("#container").append(json);
        $("#container").append("<table class='table table-bordered'><tbody>");
        $("#container>table>tbody").append(json);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var checked = + json[i].know == 1?"checked": "";
            $("#container>table>tbody").append("<tr><td>"+json[i].word+"</td><td>"+json[i].translation+"</td><td><input type='checkbox' class='know-check' name='know' know-seq='"+i+"' value='Know' "+checked+"></td><td class='delete' delete-seq='"+i+"' >❌</td></tr>");
        }
        $("#container").append("</tbody></table>");
        //SORT BY INPUT
        var $rows = $('.table tr');
        $('#word-search').keyup(function() {
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });
        //SORT BY CHECK
        $('#button-know').click(function(){
            $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').hide();
            });
            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').show();
            });
        });
        $('#button-unknow').click(function(){
            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').hide();
            });
            $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').show();
            });
        });
        $('#button-all').click(function(){
            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').show();
            });
            $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').show();
            });
        });
    }).done(function(){
        console.log("Data loaded");
        $('.know-check').click(function() {
            $.post("./modules/vocabulaire/api.php", {"edit":"edit", "id": $(this).attr("know-seq"), "value":$(this).prop( "checked" )} ).done(function(data){});
        }); 
        $('#button-ajout').click(function(){
            console.log($('#word').val());
            console.log($('#translation').val());
            $.post( "./modules/vocabulaire/api.php", {"add":"add", "word":$('#word').val(), "translation": $('#translation').val()} ).done(function(data){              
                initData();
            });
        });
        $('.delete').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).attr("delete-seq"));
            $.post( "./modules/vocabulaire/api.php", {"delete":"delete", "id": $(this).attr("delete-seq")} ).done(function(data){
                initData();
            });
        });
    });
}
initData();
//$("#container").append(data);
```

EDIT:
With JSON.stringify i can append json but i can't used this to display the table.
the result:

```
{"1":{"word":"test","translation":"poiu","know":0},"2":{"word":"zz","translation":"Rencontrer","know":0},"3":{"word":"aa","translation":"Rencontrer","know":0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from $.getJSON is an object which is converted to human readable format in your call to console.log, but cannot be appended to an html element. Try using JSON.stringify() to convert to a string.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you say that `$("#container")` is correct selector,
Just use the js function `JSON.stringify()` before append your JSON.
Why? because otherwise your `var json` is an `Object` that you can not append to your selector but just print it as `console.log()`.

```
$("#container").append(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: Ok i can display the stringify json, but i can't use it on the following json.word doesn't work, i've also try to reparse

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry, the problem is not here but on the Php who edit json